# Prove that a matrix is idempotent

Tags: matrices, idempotents

If $AB=A$ and $BA=B$ then $BA'=A'$ and $AB'=B'$ and hence prove that $A'$ and $B'$ are idempotent. $A'$ and $B'$ denote the transpose of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Since $A'$ is idempotent, I have to prove $(A')^2 = A'$

$$(A')^2 = (BA')^2 \qquad \text{or} \qquad (B'A')^2$$

I am not able to proceed after this. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

$$A^2 = (A)(A) = (AB)A = A(BA) = AB = A$$
hence $A$ is idempotent. Since $A$ is idempotent, so is $A'$.

An analogous argument shows that $B'$ is idempotent.

Comment: How can I make use of remaining two equations to prvoe the same?

Comment: Why do you have to? Weren't those just provided as hints?

Comment: Just curious...I am just thinking of why the questioner have mentioned them..

Comment: Assuming they were provided as hints, you don't have to follow them.

Comment: But you proved it without even using them right.

Comment: Yes, I just used $AB=A$ and $BA=B$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64042/discussion-between-holydevil-and-quasi).